# Dynamic Drop Down Menu and submenu php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, menu, submenu

I have a menu that needs to be created dynamically from the database. 
need to have menu and submenu

for example (wht i want):

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a> </li>
</ul>
```

below is the code i used for menu using function i want submenu as well

```
function listMenu(){
    $ans = $this->select("cat_id,cat_name","s_category","1");
    if(is_array($ans)){
        foreach($ans as $val){
            echo 
            "<li><a href=\"post-summary.php?cid=$val[0]\" >$val[1]</a></li>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "";
    }
}
```

database is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `cat_uid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cat_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cat_parent` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cat_sort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_delete` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Comment: What is `s_category` in your case? A side note: you don't need the `else { echo ""; }` part as it does nothing.

Comment: echo "no category" ... i want how to get submenu done using php mysql

Comment: You'll need to have a parent-child structure. First you'll need to select the root elements, then for each element you have to check are there child elements. If there are - print them and continue to the next element. If you have sub-sub-menu you'll need to use recursive function.

Comment: want to call data on post-summary.php?cid=catid from database... saw example of recursive function.. for recursive i have create a column link and paste the link .. wic i dont want...

Comment: If you want to create sub menu from this one category table then first of all you need to give self reference to the table.

Comment: @herr can u giv some tutorial link or example....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as menus are concerned storing the submenus as a comma seperated values in the database would come handy.

**ie** consider a table with id,menus,submenus(several submenus seperated by a comma).

```
 function listMenu(){
$ans = $this->select("menus,submenus");
if(is_array($ans)){
    foreach($ans as $val){
        echo    "<li><a href=\"post-summary.php?cid=$val[0]\" >$val[0]</a>"; //menus

        $submenu = explode(",",$val[1]);

        foreach($submenu as $values){
        echo    "<li><a href=\"post-summary.php?cid=$val[0]&proname=$values\" >$values</a></li>"; // submenus
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
 }
}
```

**try this**

```
$con    =   db_connect();
$str    =   "select menus,submenus from your_tabel  ";
$result =   mysql_query($str,$con);

while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo    "<li><a href=\"post-summary.php?cid=$arr[0]\" >$arr [0]</a>"; //menus

        $submenu = explode(",",$arr [1]);

//make sure you have several sub-menus else use a if condition here to avoid foreach error  
        foreach($submenu as $values){
        echo    "<li><a href=\"post-summary.php?cid=$arr[0]&proname=$values\" >$values</a></li>"; // submenus
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
```

**this works fine for me just tested now**

comment if working.
comment if not-working.

Comment: Comma separated values is not a good approach with databases. This will make the DB a nightmare for the guy who will manage it, not to mention the potential issues from the programmer's point of view. It's better to have a parent-child structure, so each element on it's own row.

Comment: you are correct, but in this case menus sub-links will be comparably less i think so

Comment: see the edited content, works fine for me. make sure your table is in the format mentioned (or) adjust the code slightly as per your table's requirement.

Comment: In this case yes, but in his/her next bigger project the same idea will be used, and it could be you in charge to fix the mess, right? It is just bad design pattern, and it'll be easier to learn how to do it the right way now.

Comment: pls show your database contents (i.e) use `echo "<pre>"; print_r(yourDatabaseMenu);` then post it here for some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a column, let we name it `parentId` in the `s_category` table.

Example values in there:

```
catId,catName,parentId
1,Vehicles,null
2,Planes,null
3,Cars,1
4,Bicycles,1
```

So your structure will be like:

```
- Vehicles
   - Cars
   - Bicycles
- Planes
```

You'll need to get the data like this (**to be considered as pseudocode**):

```
$topLevelItems = (select catId, catName from s_category where parentId is null)
foreach($topLevelItems as $item) {
   echo '<a href="...">$item["catName"]</a>';
   $subItems = (select catId, catName from s_category where parentId=$item['catId'])
   foreach($subItems as $subItem) {
      echo '<a href="...">$subItem["catName"]</a>';
   }
}
```

You need to re-write the SQL part to match your case. This will work if you have just one inner level, e.g. no sub-sub-menus. If you plan to use sub-sub-menus you'll need recursive function.

Comment: code i render "function listMenu(){
$topLevelItems = (select cat_id, cat_name from s_category where cat_parent is null);
foreach($topLevelItems as $item) {
   echo '<a href="...">$item["cat_name"]</a>';
   $subItems = (select cat_id, cat_name from s_category where cat_parent=$item['cat_id'])
   foreach($subItems as $subItem) {
      echo '<a href="...">$subItem["cat_name"]</a>';
   }
}
}"

Comment: getting error :"SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING " at line 6 ie 
$topLevelItems = (select cat_id, cat_name from s_category where cat_parent is null);

Comment: Don't just copy-paste it, but think about it a little bit. As I stated, the code must be considered as pseudocode. You'll need to re-write the SQL part depending on what CLI you're using to communicate with the database server. All code between ( and ) needs to be re-writed.

Answer (score 0):

created your database and write function with code and change parameters

```
  function getAllFrom($field, $table,$where = NULL, $and = NULL , $orderfield, $ordering = "DESC") {

global $con;

$getAll = $con->prepare("SELECT $field FROM $table where $where $and  ORDER BY $orderfield $ordering");

$getAll->execute();

$all = $getAll->fetchAll();

return $all;}


         <ul>
                <?php
                $allCats = getAllFrom("*", "categories", "parent = 0", "" , "cat_id", "ASC");
                     foreach ($allCats as $cat) { ?>
                      <li>
                           <?php
                     echo '<a href="categoreis.php?pagename=' . str_replace(' ', '-', $cat['name_cat']) . '&pageid=' . $cat["cat_id"] . '">

                          ' . $cat['name_cat'] . '

                          </a>';
                          ?>
                          <ul class="sub-menu[enter image description here][1]">
                                <?php
                                  $catsub = $cat['cat_id'];
                                  $SubCats = getAllFrom("*", "categories", "parent = {$catsub}", "" , "cat_id", "ASC");
                                  foreach ($SubCats as $sub) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                    <?php
                                         echo '<a href="categoreis.php?pagename=' . $sub['name_cat'] . '&pageid=' . $sub["cat_id"] . '">

                                              ' . $sub['name_cat'] . '

                                              </a>';
                                              ?>
                                       </li>
                                <?php  }
                                  ?>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                <?php   }
                 ?>
           </ul>
```